# Difference between a one-line ReadOnly property and a ReadOnly with explicit Get statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, properties

**I have a simple question.**

Is there a difference between a one-line `ReadOnly Property` and a `ReadOnly Property` with an explicit `Get` Statement?

For example, In Visual Studio 2010 I used to have to do this:

```
Private _Message As String = ""

Public ReadOnly Property Message As String
    Get
        Return _Message
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub New(Message As String)
    _Message = Message
End Sub
```

But now here I am in Visual Studio 2015 and it let's me get away with this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Message As String

Public Sub New(Message As String)
    Me.Message = Message
End Sub
```

Now I wasn't trying to me lazy, I just ran across it, expecting IntelliSense to force the `Get` Statement. So I'm left wondering if there is a difference that I should be aware of. Is it bad practice or does it do something different?

I've managed to find tons of topics and forums about `ReadOnly` in C#, but I seem to be coming up dry when searching the topic regarding vb.net.

I'll appreciate any input.
Thanks! =)

Comment: I think they pretty much do the same. I'm in no position to verify this, but you can decompile your application and inspect the code/IL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties without explicit getters and setters are simply a syntactic convenience.  There's no difference in implementation.  You should generally use the second option because it makes your code more readable.  Only use the first option if you need extra functionality in the getter.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was hoping. I'm all about readability, and when having to add a bunch of ReadOnly properties, this will come in handy. It actually would have been nice to have this convenience a few projects ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer appears to be untrue, at least for me in Visual Studio 2022.

When a property is not a constant, you have to use the multiline declaration otherwise the initial value is cached

This

```vb
    Private ReadOnly Property ConnectionFile As String
        Get
            Return gsapppath & "\connection.txt"
        End Get
    End Property
```

returns the correct path whereas this

```vb
Private ReadOnly Property ConnectionFile As String = gsapppath & "\connection.txt"
```

did not include the path because the variable `gsapppath` was not initialized at the time the class was created, yet it was initialized at the time the property was fetched.

So it's not just a syntactic convenience, there is a functional difference.